# Getting number of values in each cluster in KMeans Algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

How to get the total number of values in each clusters in KMeans Algorithm in Pandas ?

I tried the following:

```
kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters = 3, random_state = 1).fit(dataframe.iloc[:,:])
clusters = kmeans_model.labels_.count()
```

but it is not working.

My expected output is like:

```
Clusters   Number_of_values
cluster_0  932
cluster_1  931
cluster_2  930
```

Any idea how can I achieve this in Pandas ?

I tried this also, it works. It would be better if I have any other option.

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(kmeans_model.labels_))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can do this

add column for cluster numbers to the dataframe

```
kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters = 3, random_state = 1).fit(dataframe)

dataframe['kmean'] = kmeans_model.labels_
```

then count them

```
dataframe['kmean'].value_counts()
```